# Where to import file js in vue/nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

Usually I use a js code with functions to run on some events.

Now I am using nuxt.js and I wonder where to put this file or how to create a global method to use these functions in every component.
I could write the methods that I need inside every a specific component but after it wouldn't be usable outsite of it.

How to do that in vue/nuxt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So one way to do it in vue.js is by using mixins, in nuxt you can also use mixins, then you should register them as plugins, but first:

**Non global mixins**

Create an extra folder for your mixins. For example in a /mixins/myMixin.js

```
export default {
  methods: {
    commonMethod() {
      console.log('Hello')
    }
  }
}
```

Then import in a layout, page or component and add it via the mixins object:

```
<script>
  import myMixin from '~/mixins/myMixin.js'   

  export default {
    mixins: [myMixin] 
  }
</script>
```

**Global mixins**

For example in a new file plugins/mixinCommon.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
    commonMethod() {}
  }
})
```

Include the file in `nuxt.config.js` like that:
`plugins: ['~/plugins/mixinCommon']`

After that you would have the method everywhere available and call it there with this.commonMethod(). But here an advice from the vue.js docs:

> Use global mixins sparsely and carefully, because it affects every
>   single Vue instance created, including third party components. In most
>   cases, you should only use it for custom option handling like
>   demonstrated in the example above. It’s also a good idea to ship them
>   as Plugins to avoid duplicate application.

Comment: Cool now it's working, but if I have some function that before was working on document ready ```$(document).ready``` (for example the initialization of a plugin) how and where should i call it?

Comment: Once you register it as a plugin, you can call it anywhere with this.myMethod() if you register non-global mixin you need to add `mixins: [myMixin]` in export default. For plugins you need to use the plugins directory and use `Vue.use(Plugin)`.

Comment: another doubt, I think is not the best to call all mixins in every component everytime or not? Is not better to call just the functions of the method that we need in that specific component?? What do yo think?

Comment: 1) I am against global mixins, because you will most likely use them in 2-3-4 places, but load them in 40-50.
2) Yup, it's better to use import {commonMethod} from 'mixin' instead of the whole, but I am not sure if `export commonMethod` should be an object that return methods, or just a function expression..

Comment: Anyways if you can go with `mixins/blog.js` `mixins/products.js` `mixins/general.js` you would not share tons of shared functionality, without the need to change the logic for certain pages, so you would be good to go without importing specific functions.